# Large number of csv files with variable column length using Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm trying to use Dask to read a large number of csv, but I'm having issues since the number of columns varies between csv files, as does the order of the columns.

I know that packages like d6tstack [(as detailed here)](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-dask.ipynb), can help handle this, but is there a way to fix this without installing additional libraries and without taking up more disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`from_delayed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed), then you can make a function which pre-processes each of your input files as you might wish. This is totally arbitrary, so you can choose to solve the issue using your own code or any package you want to install across the cluster.

```
@dask.delayed
def read_a_file(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename). # or remote file
    do_something_with_columns
    return df_out

df = dd.from_delayed([read_a_file(f) for f in filenames], meta=...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This seems to work on a file by file basis though, while, presumably, I'd need to look at the headers of all files to determine the adequate columns and fill missing columns with NaNs. I'll look more into it.